# How to find specific element in a list with their relative position?

Tags: python, list

My list contains several strings. I want to get the next element after the element, which equals to "PlayStation". How should I do that?

```
list_ = ['PlayStation', '9th Sep 1995 (USA)29th Sep 1995 (UK/EU)28th Apr 1995 (JPN)',  'PlayStation Network', '3rd May 2007 (USA), $5.9922nd Jun 2007 (UK/EU), £3.99', '']
[element.next() for element in list_ if element == 'PythonStation']
```

I tried to achieve that by using comprehension. But it returns as [].

Comment: Can there be multiple "PlayStation" items?

Comment: Your example only returns [] as long as it doesn't find what you looking for. If you search for something thats actually in the `list_`, it raises an exception.

Guessing from your notation I assume that you expected `element` to work like a java or C++ iterator. python iterates on elements and hides the iterator from you. What your code does is equivalent to calling `[ 'PythonStation'.next() for element in list_ if element == 'PythonStation']`

Comment: What's a "PythonStation"? I'd probably love to have one :-)

Comment: @jarmod, no in my case there is only one playstation. And I found that I made a stupid mistake that it is not PythonStation. But should be PlayStation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Solution if `"PlayStation"` always occurs exactly once

Since you're looking for the position of an element, you should use `index()`:

```
list_[list_.index("PlayStation")+1]
```

That will work if you know you'll find exactly one instance of `"PlayStation"` in `list_` and it's never the last element.

##### Solution for multiple instances

If there might be several instances and you want the element after each instance, this comprehension will do that for you:

```
[y for x, y in zip(list_, list_[1:]) if x == "PlayStation"]
```

Here I'm using `zip()` to loop through pairs of each element and its successor, and printing the successor `y` if the element `x` is `"PlayStation"`.

Comment: Thank you for your complete and effective answer! It works very well!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understood the question correctly and that there zero or one `"PlayStation"` string in your list.

```
list_ = ['PlayStation', '9th Sep 1995 (USA)29th Sep 1995 (UK/EU)28th Apr 1995 (JPN)',  'PlayStation Network', '3rd May 2007 (USA), $5.9922nd Jun 2007 (UK/EU), £3.99', '']
if "PlayStation" in list_:
    index = list_.index("PlayStation")
    if index < len(list) - 1 : # if "PlayStation" is found before at the last index
        print(index+1)
    else: # "PlayStation" is found at the last index no more element after this
        print(index)
else:
    print("No match found")
```

for one or more "PlayStation" string in `list_`

```
while "PlayStation" in list_:
    index = list_.index("PlayStation")
    if index < len(list) - 1 : # if "PlayStation" is found before at the last index
        print(index+1)
    else: # "PlayStation" is found at the last index no more element after this
        print(index)
    list_ = list_[index:] #update the list to check for "PlayStation" after index in `list_`
```

Comment: I am sorry. Probably because that my question is not clear enough. But I got the answer! Thanks!